# Authentication in RESTful application on WildFly

Tags: java, security, rest, authentication, wildfly

I have two apps, server side is based on java with rest easy and client where I'm using angular js.

I used basic authentication where I generated token in first request and all requests used this token, but since I moved project to Wildfly, and there is no Tomcat this way doesn't work.

My class `TokenAuthenticator` extends `BasicAuthenticator` from Catalina;

**web.xml** has:

```
<login-config>
    <realm-name>App</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

and **jboss-web.xml**:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>App</security-domain>
    <valve>
        <class-name>package.TokenAuthenticator</class-name>
    </valve>
    <context-root>/app-server</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

In my EJB beans I'm using `@RolesAllowed` annotation to restrict access to resources.

I read that for now, Wildfly doesn't support valves.

What is my the best alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my mind and implemented form based authentication, but answering on my previous question, I should write a `ServletExtension` which adds an `AuthenticationMechanism` to `DeploymentInfo`. In `AuthenticationMechanism`, there is a authenticate() method, which authenticate users. You can find a bit info in Undertow [documentation](http://undertow.io/documentation/servlet/using-non-blocking-handlers-with-servlet.html).

Probably (before final) they will allow configuration via XML.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution than this one?